# Visual Studio- Web Tests failed with message " Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.NAP' not found in test context " and web test redirecting to login page

Tags: web-testing, webtest

our web test are working fine earlier , when we have migrated our login to AAD, web tests failed with the below reasons:

Request failed: Context parameter '$HIDDEN1.NAP' not found in test context

Redirecting to Login page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web Testing - How to fix Context parameter not found in test context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787103/web-testing-how-to-fix-context-parameter-not-found-in-test-context)

Comment: If the suggested duplicate does not help you then please [edit] your question to provide much more detail of the problem. Please read the [help] pages on how to write a good question.